# logstash to s3 prefix doesn't work properly

Tags: amazon-s3, logstash

`logstash` s3 output plugin doesn't seem to know how to take variables. Here's my `logstash` output configuration's jinja2 template:

```
output {
  if "backup" in [tags] {
    s3 {
      access_key_id => "{{ s3.access_key_id }}"             
      secret_access_key => "{{ s3.secret_access_key }}" 
      region => "{{ s3.region }}"           
      bucket => "{{ s3.bucket }}" 
      size_file => {{ s3.size_file }}                        
      time_file => {{ s3.time_file }}   
      codec => "json_lines"                        
      canned_acl => "private"      
      prefix => "{{ hostvars.gateway.name }}/{{ project_id }}-{%type}/"            
    }
  }
}
```

Each log entry contains a `type` field indicating the nature of the log. So I want to separate the backup files on s3 by `type`. The backup is put to s3 fine, except `{%type}` isn't substituted by the log item's `type` value. Instead the filename contains "-{%type}" as is. I don't know if it's my configuration problem or it's the actual desired behaviour. I'm using `logstash-2.2.0`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a [known bug](https://github.com/logstash-plugins/logstash-output-s3/issues/16) that variables aren't allowed in 'prefix'.

Comment: This pull request supposedly fixes it, haven't had a chance to verify that it works in current released version yet.
https://github.com/logstash-plugins/logstash-output-s3/pull/17